# how can I get the output of a function as data frame?

Tags: r, function

in R, i write a function. The output of the function has several  columns. how can I have the output as a data frame or matrix, so that i can operate on each column separately? Thanks

Comment: please see how to make an [awesome reproducible example for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Having said that:

```
myfunc <- function() {
  vec1 <- 1:10
  vec2 <- letters[1:10]
  return(data.frame(vec1, vec2))
}

myfunc()
##    vec1 vec2
## 1     1    a
## 2     2    b
## 3     3    c
## 4     4    d
## 5     5    e
## 6     6    f
## 7     7    g
## 8     8    h
## 9     9    i
## 10   10    j
```

makes and returns a data frame from two vectors and should be an example you can extend for your purposes.